# How do you use R in Scribus render frames?

Tags: r, scribus

Scribus (1.4) supports directly generating and embedding output from external programs via render frames, but the default installation only supports LaTeX, Lilypond, Gnuplot, Dot and POV-Ray. Others can be added. The [Scribus wiki](http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Help:Manual_Renderframes#Configuration) has some documentation.

By calling Rscript Scribus should automatically generate the pdf output, but I can't get it to work. Calling Rscript manually (i.e. via command line) works just fine. Any ideas how the Rscript command in the render frame config should be formatted?

Sample render frame config (not working for me):

```
<editorsettings description="R">
<executable command="Rscript %file" />
<imagefile extension=".pdf"/>
<empty-frame-text>
</empty-frame-text>
<preamble>
</preamble>
<postamble></postamble>
</editorsettings>
```

Sample plot:

```
x <- 1:10
plot(x)
```